# How to use swagger via attributes

Tags: php, laravel, swagger

I use Swagger for Laravel 9.
My code not generation Swagger via php artisan l5-swagger:generation

I building attributes for Body, my code:

```
#[OA\Post(
        path: 'api/login',
        requestBody: new OA\RequestBody(
            ref: null,
            description: "Write data for authorization",
            required: true,
            content: new OA\JsonContent(
                properties: [
                    new OA\Property(
                        property: "login",
                        required: true,
                        type: "string",
                        format: "text",
                        example: "email@host.ru",
                    ),
                ]
            ),

        ),
        tags: ["Account"])]
    #[OA\Response(ref: "Authorization in system, get API Token.", response: 200)]
```

Code not generation JSON for Swagger, Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove in Model line.
Old:

```php
#[OAT\Schema(
    title: "Cabinet",
    description: "Cabinet model",
    xml: new OAT\XML(name: "Cabinet")
)]
```

New:

```php
#[OAT\Schema(
    title: "Cabinet",
    description: "Cabinet model"
)]
```

Remove line:

```
xml: new OAT\XML(name: "Cabinet")
```